# Maximum-weight set of cliques of size 3 with no common vertices in undirected graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, weighted-graphs, clique

I'm looking for an algorithm/insight into a problem that's an extension of the [Maximum Weight Matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_weight_matching) problem. The maximum weight matching problem looks for the max-weight set of edges that contain 0 common vertices. The problem can be thought of as grouping the vertices into sets of 2 such that no vertex belongs to more than 1 group.

I'm looking to extend the problem such that the vertices can be split into groups of 3. For an undirected graph, this translates into looking for cliques/cycles of size 3 that do not contain common vertices. Any guidance on how to approach this problem either deterministically or with an approximation/heuristic algorithm?

Note: the graphs I'm working with are typically dense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is NP-complete even when all edge weights are 1, since that restriction is equivalent to the problem Partition Into Triangles, which "Computers and Intractability" (Garey and Johnson, 1979) lists as NP-complete on p. 192, attributing the result to a personal communication from T. J. Schaefer in 1974, apparently based on a reduction from 3-Dimensional Matching.

So, no efficient algorithm can be expected. For an exponential-time exact algorithm, I would probably try branch and bound intertwined with maximum bipartite (2-)matching, as follows: At each stage, we have a vertex $v_i$, which we will take to be the lowest-numbered vertex of a triangle, and the decision is which of its neighbour vertices $v_j$ should become the highest-numbered vertex in the triangle. For each possible $v_j$, to test feasibility of the choice, create a new, bipartite graph with a vertex for each low+high vertex pair decided so far, as well as a vertex for each as-yet unprocessed vertex, and an edge between two vertices whenever the low+high pair represented by one would form a triangle in the original graph with the other *and* the latter vertex is numbered between the low and high vertices represented by the former. Run maximum bipartite matching on this new graph, and check that every low+high pair decided so far is saturated (adjacent to a matched edge) -- if this fails, then the current assignment of low+high vertices cannot be extended to a full triangle partition and the branch can be pruned. I think this algorithm, which chooses just 2 vertices within each triangle, will result in B&B tree depths of around 2/3rds the fully naive approach in which all 3 vertices of each triangle are chosen.